# Как лучше передать переменную классу Controller?

Tags: java, многопоточность, javafx, сокет, чат

Делаю чат на javа, но столкнулся с проблемой. Мне нужно, чтобы сервер пользователя получал сообщение от централизованного сервера и выводил все сообщения на экран. По [некоторым обстоятельствам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1065964/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-nullpointerexception-%D0%B2-javafx), я не могу в классе сервера обращаться к методам/полям контроллера чата, поэтому мне пришла идея передавать какую-то статичную переменную, по типу `Arraylist`, контроллеру.
Я еще не очень опытен в Java, поэтому вопрос в том, настолько это эффективно и как лучше всего это сделать?
Код моего сервера:

```java
package sample;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.Scanner;

import static sample.chatcontroller.ClientPort;
import static sample.chatcontroller.ServerPort;

class ClientServer implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(ClientPort)) {
        while (true) {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
                ServerPort = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
                String msg = scanner.nextLine();//само сообщение
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Код моего контроллера:

```java
package sample;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.*;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class chatcontroller{
    public static String name = "client";
    public static int ClientPort = 6777;
    public static int ServerPort = 7777;
    @FXML
    private TextField messagefield;

    @FXML
    private Button sendbutton;

    @FXML
    private Button exitbutton;

    @FXML
    private Button configbutton;

    @FXML
    private Button onlyadminbutton;

    @FXML
    public TextArea textarea;

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        new Thread(new ClientServer()).start();
        exitbutton.setOnAction(event -> {
            exitbutton.getScene().getWindow().hide();
            FXMLLoader loader1 = new FXMLLoader();             //выход из чата
            loader1.setLocation(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
            try {
                loader1.load();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Parent root1 = loader1.getRoot();
            Stage stage1 = new Stage();
            stage1.setScene(new Scene(root1));
            stage1.showAndWait();
        });
        sendbutton.setOnAction(e -> {
            String input = messagefield.getText();
            if (!input.isEmpty()) {
                SendMSG(input);
                Platform.runLater(()-> textarea.appendText("Пользователь " + name + " написал " + input + "\n"));
                messagefield.clear();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Так же буду благодарен за советы по улучшению моего стиля программирования.

Comment: Грязное решение которое мне помогло когда-то, передать контроллер как переменную, в другой класс, где она являлась статической и я мог обратиться к ней из любого пакета и класса.
Это будет работать, но я знаю что это неправильно.

Comment: Добавьте гетер и сетер для этих переменных

Comment: @PerfectVoyage, пытался так сделать еще давно, все так же `NullPointerExecption`.... 
И даже не в классе сервера, а в классе контроллера :/

Comment: @Алексейг JavaFX так не работает.

Comment: @Shad0wCloud покажите пример передачи ? По поводу кода - Название класса ВСЕГДА с большой буквы. Помнится вы вчера задавали этот же вопрос, а ошибки у вас остались

Comment: @PerfectVoyage, немного ошибся, я пытался сделать `TextArea` статичной, а сам контроллер не пытался сделать статичным. Буду признателен, если подскажете, как сделать сам контроллер статичным.
Я запомнил все советы с прошлого вопроса, но пока не применил знания к этому проекту :/

Comment: @Shad0wCloud ок. Но это решение не является ВЕРНЫМ.
1. Исправить название класса на class Сhatcontroller

2. В классе ClientServer  объявить поле public static Сhatcontroller ccr (Не инициализировать его)

3. В методе initialize() у вашего контроллера, передать контроллер через класс ClientServer.ccr = this. Вуаля, вы отдали ваш контроллер статическому полю другого класса при загрузке.

4. Но вы скорее всего получите уже другую ошибку, связанную с многопоточностью в JavaFX

Comment: @PerfectVoyage, сработало! Оно работает(даже без ошибок) :D
Спасибо за советы и за исправление название моего названия класса. Если хотите, можете ответить на мой вопрос, я отмечу его, как верным.

Comment: @Shad0wCloud спасибо ) но меня заминусуют профи :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение проблемы - передать контроллер классу сервера,

1. В классе сервера объявить поле `static Chatcontroller ccr;`
2. В методе `initialize()` у контроллера, передать контроллер через класс `ClientServer.ccr = this`
   В результате передачи контроллера, можно будет обратиться к TextArea в классе контроллера `ccr.textarea.appendText(msg);`

Спасибо пользователю [@PerfectVoyage](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/345122/perfect-voyage) за решение проблемы.