# JavaFX Как мне обратиться к эллементам из контроллера из других классов? Выдаёт ошибки, помогите пожалуйста

Tags: java, javafx

```
package sample.SupportClasses;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import sample.Locations.*;
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 820, 550));
        primaryStage.show();

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}




package sample.SupportClasses;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import sample.Locations.City;

public class Controller {
    @FXML
    public TextArea textAreaMain;

    @FXML
    public ImageView imageViewLockations;

    @FXML
    public Button buttonLockOne;

    @FXML
    public Button buttonLockTwo;

    @FXML
    public Button buttonLockThree;

    @FXML
    public Button buttonLockFore;

    private LocationsSample locationsSample;
//    public Controller(){
//        this.locationsSample = new LocationsSample();
//    }

    public Button getButtonLockOne() {
        return buttonLockOne;
    }
    public Button getButtonLockTwo() {
        return buttonLockTwo;
    }
    public Button getButtonLockThree() {
        return buttonLockThree;
    }
    public Button getButtonLockFore() {
        return buttonLockFore;
    }

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        City city = new City();
        //city.startCity();
    }

}




package sample.Locations;
import sample.SupportClasses.Controller;
import sample.SupportClasses.LocationsLoader;
import sample.SupportClasses.LocationsSample;
public class City {

    public City(){
        LocationsSample locationsSample = new LocationsSample();
        System.out.println("asd");
        locationsSample.setElements(4, "@../img/backgroundCityImage.png");
    }

    public void startCity(){

    }
}




package sample.SupportClasses;

import sample.Locations.City;

public class LocationsSample {


    public void setElements(int quantityButtons, String srcImage){
        LocationsLoader locationsLoader = new LocationsLoader();
        locationsLoader.disableButtons();
        locationsLoader.activateButtons(quantityButtons);
        locationsLoader.setImage(srcImage);
    }
}




package sample.SupportClasses;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;

public class LocationsLoader{
    Controller controller = new Controller();

    public void disableButtons(){
        controller.buttonLockOne.setDisable(true);
        controller.buttonLockOne.setVisible(false);
        controller.buttonLockTwo.setDisable(true);
        controller.buttonLockTwo.setVisible(false);
        controller.buttonLockThree.setDisable(true);
        controller.buttonLockThree.setVisible(false);
        controller.buttonLockFore.setDisable(true);
        controller.buttonLockFore.setVisible(false);

//        controller.getButtonLockOne().setDisable(true);
//        controller.getButtonLockOne().setVisible(false);
//        controller.getButtonLockTwo().setDisable(true);
//        controller.getButtonLockTwo().setVisible(false);
//        controller.getButtonLockThree().setDisable(true);
//        controller.getButtonLockThree().setVisible(false);
//        controller.getButtonLockFore().setDisable(true);
//        controller.getButtonLockFore().setVisible(false);


    }

    public void activateButtons(int a){
        controller.buttonLockOne.setDisable(false);
        controller.buttonLockTwo.setDisable(false);
        controller.buttonLockThree.setDisable(false);
        controller.buttonLockFore.setDisable(false);

        for(int i = 0; i <=a; i++){
            if(i == 1){controller.buttonLockOne.setDisable(false); controller.buttonLockOne.setVisible(true);};
            if(i == 2){controller.buttonLockTwo.setDisable(false); controller.buttonLockTwo.setVisible(true);};
            if(i == 3){controller.buttonLockThree.setDisable(false); controller.buttonLockThree.setVisible(true);};
            if(i == 4){controller.buttonLockFore.setDisable(false); controller.buttonLockFore.setVisible(true);};
        }
    }

    public void setImage(String srcImage){
        Image image = new Image(srcImage);
        controller.imageViewLockations.setImage(image);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPD Такой вопрос уже [был](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1066208/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%83-controller?noredirect=1#comment1827402_1066208)

```
 Controller controller = new Controller();
```

Вы создали новый контроллер, который ничего не знает, о вашем существующем контроллере. Не инициализируйте его в классе **LocationsLoader** . Можете пометить поле как static

```
public static Controller controller;
```

и тогда в вашем контроллере здесь, просто передайте ссылку.

```
@FXML
    void initialize() {
        LocationsLoader.controller = this;
        City city = new City();
        //city.startCity();
    }
```

Данный способ слишком грубый, и вам следует поискать информацию про fx root. Но если вам нужно здесь и сейчас...флаг в руки )